How to remove overflow on printing
I have a page that has a button to print, but I have a problem. the scrollbar appears regardless of the number of items on the page, I would like to remove the scrollbar and show all items when clicking to print. In the example image I posted, 48 items should appear, but there are only 16, and I believe the scrollbar is to blame. overflow is no longer working

<div *ngIf="showReport">
    <div class="report-container">
      <!-- Cabeçalho do relatório e resumo -->
      <div class="report-header">
        <div class="summary-container">
          <div class="summary-items">
            <div *ngFor="let summaryItem of reportItems.summary">
              <span style="font-weight: bold">{{summaryItem.label}}</span> {{summaryItem.value}}
            </div>
          </div>
          <ion-row *ngIf="reportItems.qrCode" class="qr-code-container">
            <qrcode
              [qrdata]="reportItems.qrCode"
              [width]="160"
              [errorCorrectionLevel]="'L'"
              [elementType]="'svg'"
              [scale]="1"
            ></qrcode>
          </ion-row>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <!-- Botão de impressão -->
      <div class="button-container no-print">
        <button id="print-button" class="track-button" (click)="printReport()">Imprimir Relatório</button>
      </div>
  
      <!-- Lista de itens do relatório -->
      <div id="printable-report" class="report-list">
        <ion-list id="item-grid">
          <ion-item style="font-weight: bold" class="table-header">
            <ion-label>Nº</ion-label>
            <ion-label>Lote Bobina</ion-label>
            <ion-label>Comprimento (m)</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
          <!-- Iteração sobre os itens reais do relatório -->
          <ion-item *ngFor="let item of [].constructor(48); let i = index" class="table-row">
            <ion-label>{{ i + 1 }}</ion-label>
            <ion-label>DC1D17924T2/02</ion-label>
            <ion-label>100</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


@media screen {
  @page {
    size: auto;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    page-break-after: always;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height:fit-content;

  }
}
@media print {
  @page {
    size: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden !important;
    page-break-after: always;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
  }
}


It would be easier to help if you create a Minimal, Reproducible Example and use Stack Snippets to make a live demo.
